# SoapUI groovy script displays popup where it shouldn't

Tags: groovy, soapui

I need to format some xml in the groovy script in SoapUI. I'm using method `groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(xmlString)`

According to the [javadoc](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/xml/XmlUtil.html#serialize-java.lang.String-), this static method should return formatted String. But the SoapUI also displays a popup window with the formatted String. Is there some way I can prevent that? I have no idea why this happens.

[image]

- SoapUI version 5.4.0 on Linux

Answer (score 1):

That is because of the last statement.

Hope you need to log that formatted xml, then add below statement at the end of your script:

```
log.info formatted
```

Comment: I don't need to log that. I'm inserting this formatted xml into a request. It works fine, I just don't understand why I get the popup window. The method should just return a String, not display anything. So this is some SoapUI quirk I want to get rid off.

Comment: I've found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24620763/2266098
Apparently, I need to add `return` at the end of the script. Otherwise the last executed statement result is displayed in the popup.